# Studying Galois Cohomology from Category Theory.

Tags: reference-request, soft-question, category-theory, topos-theory, galois-cohomology

I am a masters student with background in Category Theory - I also know some Topos Theory. I would like to ask if you think it would be possible to start studying Galois Cohomology without any knowledge of either group cohomology or Galois theory. I know this probably sounds too stupid to ask, but please let me explain (and please feel free to correct me if I am wrong). I am interested in eventually attempting to learn Etale Cohomology; and I am quite confident that Etale Cohomology has evolved from Galois Cohomology. So maybe it would be wiser to learn that first.

I would really like to know what people think the "orthodox" way/path for learning these theories is. I am grateful to any answer.

Comment: If you already know some topos theory you may as well just learn topos cohomology.

Comment: What do you mean by topos cohomology? And is there any text/paper about it that I can learn from? Thanks!

Comment: You can either learn it from the original source (SGA 4) or from Johnstone's _Topos theory_ [2014 Dover reprint].

Comment: Thanks! And, would that, in your opinion, be useful in understanding other cohomology theories - like Galois and Etale? In the way that someone understands the notion of a product of topological spaces after learning about limits in categories?

Comment: No, not really. Topos cohomology gets you as far as the definition and the very basic properties. There's much more going on than can be said in the general case.

Comment: Ok...and then, what do you suggest? I guess you mention topos cohomology for "getting into the spirit of cohomology". But then? How would you suggest continuing? Do you have any particular reference for either Galois or Etale, for someone with my background, as mentioned above (plus, faithfully, topos cohomology)?